# Animation not firing at the start of the page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I wanted to show an animation that my container increases its width and height just at the start of the page every time.
Here it directly takes the values of `initstate` and doesn't show any animation.

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image:DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black54, BlendMode.darken),
                      image: AssetImage("lib/images/read.jpg"),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Colors.yellowAccent,
                          Colors.blueAccent,
                        ]
                    )
                ),
                width: width,
                height: height,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Quote_Categories())
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Reader',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

```
height=400;
width=250;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    registernotification();
    width=200;
    height=200;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [initState:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)
> Called when this object is inserted into the tree.

So basically you are having `width:200` and  `height = 200` before reading the value, because those are inside  `initState`. You can simply create a `Future method` with  `Duration.zero` and use `setState` to update the UI.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    changeContainerSize();
  }

  changeContainerSize() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        width = 200;
        height = 200;
      });
    });
  }
```

Or use `addPostFrameCallback`

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {
        width = 200;
        height = 200;
      });
    });
  }
```